# Can't access site using external IP. Get error "invalid fingerprint"

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to access my Google Compute Engine VM at 104.197.83.224. I tried to allow HTTP and HTTPS traffic but it errors out both times. It gives the error Invalid Fingerprint.

Could use some help. Thanks!

Also, although I haven't used my VM at all, I've gotten a bunch of requests on it. And its starting to charge me even though I'm not using it. How can I prevent that?

Comment: I'm also having the same error. Have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: How are you trying to access your instance? By SFTP or SSH? Does it work when you try to SSH through the developers console? It sounds like it is a keys issue.

Comment: Even I cant add new SSH keys. It is showing Invalid fingerprint.

Comment: i have same problem,what you did

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've stored a previous SSH key for that IP address in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. Check that file for entries that have the same IP address as your current instance and remove them.

Unfortunately, SSH assumes that IP addresses and SSH keys are assigned fairly statically (rather than using signatures from some central trust authority like SSL), which is a problem when you start to have cloud services which may assign the same IP address to different VMs several times during one day (if the VMs are started and shut down quickly, for example). I think that the `gcloud ssh` comm